# Custom urls - giving each user a url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am building a website and I would like to customize the users' profile so their profile url shares their name. For example, the website domain would be www.example.com and the users' url  would be www.example.com/username.

I am assuming this is a convention because I see this all around the web. Is this done by giving each user their own directory and how painstaking would that be?

Comment: This is done by url rewriting, which can be accomplished using .htaccess (which you tagged yourself).

Comment: take a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616201/relative-urls-with-htaccess?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really can't justify using htaccess for something like this. I only use htaccess to route everything through one php file (my root `index.php`) and let php sort out how to handle the url. For example, you could do this:

```
$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
$pieces = explode('/', $uri);
$username = $pieces[0];
```

Then do something with `$username`.

The way I parse and use my url's is a bit more complicated than this, but it wouldn't be relevant to your question. Just make sure whatever you do is able to account for any possible query strings, etc.

mod-rewrite is not great for performance, so I wouldn't abuse it.

#### Updated based on your comments.

Here's just a slight expansion on my original code sample:

```
//.htaccess - route all requests through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|css|js|html)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

and this is an example of what you could do in index.php:

```
$pieces = preg_split('-/-', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$username = $pieces[0];

include "users/{$username}.php";
```

Now you could visit `mysite.com/myUserNameHere`, the request goes to `index.php` which parses out the username and includes a file for that user.

That takes care of the routing just like you asked. I said that my routing is more complicated, but my use is a lot more complicated, so it isn't relevant. I only warned that my code here doesn't account for a url with a query string attached, like "mysite.com/someUser/?foo=bar". It's a simple process to parse the url without the query string and you should be able to handle that. If you need further assistance parsing the url, then make a post asking about that.

Comment: You said your urls are more complicated that what you have here, so please tell me where I can learn to do complicated urls. My project requires the user not so see the .php extensions even though the pages on the back have extensions and I don't know how to do these things.

Comment: @Iamcoder I updated my answer with exact code to parse the username and include something specific to that user. There are a lot of ways to solve your problem, but deciding what you really want to do will require a lot of study on your part.

Comment: @lamcoder did you appreciate my answer? If there is a helpful answer here, please click the accept checkmark next to the one you think is the best.

Comment: @Iamcoder there are up and down arrows with a number in between - the checkmark is underneath that.

Comment: I see the arrows now. I try to vote you up but it says I have to have 15 reputations in order to vote you up. Did you vote on my question?

Comment: @www.matemingler.com I wasn't referring to those. The checkmark, not the arrows. The checkmark is underneath those. This will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). I think the following should do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?username=$1 [NC]
```

This will convert the displayed url (`www.example.com/myusername`), to an url with a GET parameter for your index.php. This new url that you can use internally will look like this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?username=myusername
```

Update: Here is an extra clarification to answer the questions in your comment:

The RewriteRule above does exactly what you are asking. The user can enter an url like `www.example.com/username`, which will be internally rewritten (without the user ever noticing it) to `www.example.com/index.php?username=myusername`. That way you can access the get variable (`$_GET["username"]`), without the user ever seeing it exists.

Nice tutorials can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) and [here](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs).

Comment: No Patrick, what I mean I want the link to the user's profile to be link this www.example.com/username so the user could put it on a business card and things of that nature. When the user click "My Profile" the link will be www.example.com/username. One issue I have with this is that I need the user's username from the link itself to pull information from the database. So if I don't have a get variable from the url how will this work? Can you direct me to some tutorials as I'd also like to remove .php from all my links and still get the variables as well. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Patrick thanks for the links. I made a mistake in my posting. What I want is for the value of the variable to be the username so I can query the database with the username . I will study the links you gave me to get a better grasp of things.

Comment: `I put this directive in httpd.conf file, but upon doing so apache doesn't work``<Directory>` `RewriteEngine On` `Options +MultiViews` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f`
`RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f`
`RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ ad.php?username=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]` `</Directory>`

Comment: These are some of the errors:`[Thu Dec 26 21:42:54.790828 2013] [core:notice] [pid 3996:tid 456] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'`
`[Thu Dec 26 21:42:54.792803 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3996:tid 456] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6352`
`[Thu Dec 26 21:42:55.176419 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6352:tid 340] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.`
`[Sun Dec 29 10:07:34.187381 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3996:tid 456] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.`

Comment: This doesn't say anything about the problem, I think you're better of creating a new question with this specific problems. You cannot put enough information into comments to solve this fast and effectively.

Comment: What should the question say? I asked a question pertaining to this topic and it got remove by the moderators because they say it was about server and stackoverflow it not about that.

Comment: @Iamcoder, it should at least include the .htaccess you are using and the error apache gives your for that htaccess files.

Comment: I did that and I got punished on here. Do you have a facebook or the like where I can send you the error?

Comment: @www.matemingler.com, I'm sure you'll get help if you create a proper question here. Plenty of questions like that have been asked. Otherwise you can still create an account on server stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean are not 'real' URIs, but are rewrites. So with .htaccess you can redirect the viewing user from a regular URI like `example.com/user` to `example.com/users.php?name=user` without him seeing it.

It is kind of a convention, as it's useful to make URIs more readable, it also *can* let Google give a better ranking for that page as there might be keywords in the URI and the URI is shorter, so the keywords stand out better.

Here's a basic rewrite, which is to place in your .htaccess file somewhere on your server (mostly in the root so it can control all subfolders from there on):

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users.php?name=$1 [NC]
```